# Why is my JavaScript code not workinig. alert box not showing

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

here is my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="launchbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1">Show Current Value</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


        Name: <input type="text" id="id_name" value="jerry">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

and my js page:

```
$(function(){

    alert($("#id_name").val());
    $("#launchbtn").click(function(){
        $("#id_name").val('change');

    });

    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        alert($("#id_name").val());
        });

)};
```

I was testing stuff with javascript when all of a sudden all of my js code stopped working. My alert box is not showing. Nor is the value of my input changing. I tried solving it for 2 hours with no result. I'm very new to javascript any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have two versions of jQuery linked? You should not have two versions. That is going to lead to other problems.

Comment: Your brackets at the end are not properly closed. it should be `})` instead of `)}`. The code is fine.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Your browser should clearly have an error in the console. Learn to use your developer tools. Proper indenting of your code will allow you to see it more. Or adding something like ESLint to your IDE will really point it out.

Comment: Look at the browser console (Right-click and inspect element or in Chrome it is F12). There you can see syntax errors and the like.

Comment: thanks its working now. Fixed the bracket and deleted a jquery link. I did not know there was a thing called browser console. It is going to make my problem solving a alot easier now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If I test your code, all I see is a syntax error, change

```
)};
```

to

```
});
```

Is that all?

Comment: Typo/syntax errors answers must be added as comments, your answer does not add any insightful value as its a syntax error

Comment: Havent seen this rule in

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

But ty for beeing 'polite'